# Matlab: Conversion from cell to double

Tags: matlab, cell

I'm trying to store the color values given by the `impixel` function into a matrix or an array of some sort.

```
B = cell(301, 51);
for R = 200: 500
for C = 175 : 225
    B(R-199,C-174) = impixel(I,R,C);
end
end
```

I created a cell array to hold the values, but I keep getting the following error:

> "Conversion to cell from double is not possible."

Where is my error? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of [`impixel`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/impixel.html), it states that its outputs are all either of class `double` or `single`.

In your code, you define `B` as a cell array. There is no problem storing the output of `impixel` in `B`. However, if you index it with the parenthesis `()`, it expects the value assigned to also be a cell. You want to assign the output of `impixel` to a particular element of `B`, and need to use the curly braces `{}` to refer to the element. I believe changing your code to

```
B{R-199,C-174} = impixel(I,R,C);
```

may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error should be in this line:

```
B(R-199,C-174) = impixel(I,R,C);
```

`impixel` in this case returned a `double` type, while B is a `cell` type.